# Possible to use cache drive for data drives?

Tags: ssd, cache

I have a 256GB SSD that I want to use for the OS and Apps. I also have another 64GB SSD as a spare. The computer has 3 - 2TB HD's in RAID 3. Can I use the 64GB as a cache drive for the RAID 5?

RAID is from the motherboard. Not from a dedicated controller.